# Property from Objective-C class is not visible in Swift subclass when that property is from Swift Package

Tags: swift, objective-c, swift-package

I have a class hierarchy like this: `MySwiftSubViewController` -> `ViewController` -> `UIViewController`. Here is the code:

```objectivec
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SwiftClassFromPackage;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) SwiftClassFromPackage* _Nullable someSwiftObjectFromPackage;

@end
```

This class is using a type from an SwiftPackage for a property. Inside the Objective-C class it seems to be fine:

```objectivec
#import "ViewController.h"
@import MyPackage;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _someSwiftObjectFromPackage = [[SwiftClassFromPackage alloc] init];
}
@end
```

But in the Swift subclass it got an compile error when I use this property like this:

```swift
import UIKit
import MyPackage

class MySwiftSubViewController: ViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("\(self.someSwiftObjectFromPackage.text)") 
        // Value of type 'MySwiftSubViewController' has no member 'someSwiftObjectFromPackage'
    }
}
```

When I use this `SwiftClassFromPackage` class outside the package then it is working but not when it is coming from an package.

Any suggestions why this is not working?

Comment: Interface of Objective-C class that needs to be visible by swift must be imported in the bridging header file in your project. On the other direction, Swift class are automatically converted to Objective-C interface in the Project-Swift.h file which must be included in Objective-C or prefix header.

Comment: Thank you for your response. These things seems to be fine. My Objective-C class is visible to the Swift class and vice versa. Also the class from the Swift Package is visible to both. What is causing problems is the inheritance from Objective-C to Swift. The sub class in Swift will not get functions or properties from the Objective-C class when it is using the class from the Swift Package as type.